# Check if user is logged in and if so view accounts in text file

Tags: python, authentication

```
elif choice == "4":
        if login == True:
            with open('accounts.txt') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                print(contents)
        else:
            print("You must be logged into view accounts")
```

I need this program to check if the user is logged in (when the user is logged in login=true) if they are i need it to print a text file, or if they are not logged in,  print you must be logged in to view accounts

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? edit your question to include a detailed explanation of the issue and the stacktrace/error message if you have any.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it doesn't work, it just loops, if you would like i can share it here?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TZy9SQQn